# How to Implement "Handoff to human " in microsoft teams bot app (using teams toolkit)? Is it possible using typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams

Iam stuck at implementing "handoff conversation to human agent mechanism" using typescript , microsoftbot framework and teams toolkit. Please help me to find out a way on this.

Comment: If you are looking for handoff in teams, Could you please check [Handoff overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/health-bot/handoff)? Try if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download and install the latest version of Teams Toolkit in VSC extension market, which should be the preview 2.0.0 version. After installed, you can find samples in the Teams Toolkit, there is a FAQ sample which is a bot app forwarding questions to human expert. That may be a good sample for you. Or you can find the sample here https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-samples

Answer (score 0):

Handoff functionality is disabled by default. To use this feature activate handoff from your management portal. Navigate to Configuration > Conversation > Human handoff and enable handoff. To Implement “Handoff to human ” in microsoft teams bot app please check [Handoff overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/health-bot/handoff).

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha-MSFT  .  Could you share me any sample code in typescript or any code links ,so I will get a better understanding.

Comment: Currently we don't have any samples in type script